# SWT Examples in eclipse Window->Show View

Tags: eclipse, swt

I'm following this article about SWT
http://www.cs.umanitoba.ca/~eclipse/4-Layouts.pdf

In the 2nd image on the 2nd page it shows opening SWT Layouts under the Show View menu in Eclipse.

The problem is that I don't have that "Eclipse Examples" folder in Show View!
How can I do?

Thank you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the [SWT Examples](https://www.eclipse.org/swt/examples.php) plug-in.